# How to use "MDCOutlinedTextField" in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, textfield

I need textfield like below image

[image]

so i am using [material-components-ios](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios) framework, for that i have added textfield in storyboard and given its class name to `MDCTextField` and code

```
import UIKit

import MaterialComponents
class LoginVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var emailTF: MDCTextField!

var textFieldControllerFloating: MDCTextInputControllerOutlined?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  //  setupEditText()
    
    textFieldControllerFloating = MDCTextInputControllerOutlined(textInput: emailTF)

    textFieldControllerFloating?.activeColor = UIColor.lightGray
    textFieldControllerFloating?.floatingPlaceholderActiveColor = UIColor.green
    textFieldControllerFloating?.normalColor = UIColor.lightGray
    textFieldControllerFloating?.inlinePlaceholderColor = UIColor.lightGray
    
}
```

with this code o/p coming perfect but showing warning

**warning:**

> 'MDCTextField' is deprecated: MDCTextField and its associated classes are deprecated. Please use TextControls instead.

so i have added another framework [TextControls](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/tree/develop/components/TextControls) here i have added `pod 'MaterialComponents/TextControls+OutlinedTextFields'` and added textfield in stroyboard and given its class to `MDCOutlinedTextField` and added below code

```
 import UIKit
 import MaterialComponents.MaterialTextControls_OutlinedTextFields

class LoginVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var emailTF: MDCOutlinedTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTF: MDCOutlinedTextField!
}
}
```

**but o/p like below**: no floating placeholder text and small height as well why?, where am i wrong.. how to get textfield with height 50 and floating placeholder border like above image, please do help.

**EDIT:** i need eye button for password textfield like this how to do with `MDCOutlinedTextField`?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [example](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/tree/develop/components/TextControls#swift-3) try to set `label.text` property like that

```
textField.label.text = "Phone number"
```

As for text field height you can set it for instance with a constraint in Interface Builder

Comment: i need eye button for password textfield how to add?

Comment: i have edited my question with password textfield image at the end of the question.. like that how to do?

Comment: @User123 try to use your custom view assigning it to `trailingView` property